# Cannot enable COAP on Heroku deployed app

Tags: java, heroku, coap

I developed a Spring application exposing both REST and COAP endopoints and I deployed it on Heroku. I can reach the REST endopoints, but I get a timeout when trying to reach the coap endpoint.
Locally everything works.

Do I need to enable coap on Heroku? Is it possible?

Comment: Is the COAP on a different port?

Comment: Right now it is on the same, I can try on a different one though

Answer (score 2):

CoAP uses UDP, and I guess REST means HTTP/TCP.
I don't know Heroku, but I guess you have to specific that.
For docker ist appending /udp to the portnumber 5683:5683/udp

Comment: heroku's router only supports HTTP. You can use `heroku ps:forward` to access it locally, or a tool like ngrok https://github.com/jkutner/heroku-buildpack-ngrok